# Django create record in other table

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a model as below:

```
class Investee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

There is of course the User model that comes with django outta the box.
What I'm trying to do is once a user registers and an entry is created in that model, I immediately create an entry in the Investee model but it ain't working. What could be wrong? My code for now is:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
user.first_name = firstname
user.last_name = lastname
user.save()
if (user_type == 1):
           investee = Investee(user=user)
           investee.save()
```

Comment: What does "it  ain't working" mean? What do you see? And are you sure that `user_type` is 1?

Answer (score 0):

Actually that was the problem...my bad. Was getting the user_type from a radio box so I should have done:

```
if (user_type) == "1":
....
```

instead of:

```
if (user_type) == 1:
...
```

Comment: Even better, you should use a form, which will normalize the values to the correct type.